# Error when trying to restore backup

Tags: postgresql, restore

This line(518):

```
COPY wp_commentmeta (meta_id, comment_id, meta_key, meta_value) FROM stdin;
\.
```

is giving this error:

`[ERROR    ] 518.0: syntax error, unexpected character`

What is this?

I have done backup before with this database, and now I'm just trying to restore all the tables back to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: ...a (meta_id, comment_id, meta_key, meta_value) FROM stdin; \.
                                                                     ^


********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 77
```

points to the \ in the `\.` as being the issue. 
Are you sure you require the `\.`?

Per the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html):

> End of data can be represented by a single line containing just
>   backslash-period (.). **An end-of-data marker is not necessary when
>   reading from a file, since the end of file serves perfectly well**; it
>   is needed only when copying data to or from client applications using
>   pre-3.0 client protocol.

Try removing your `\.` from the line and see if your copy works as expected.

Comment: Hi Rober, I did removed \. and now I have another error: `528.0: syntax error, unexpected INTEGER VALUE` .. this is on this line: `1 1 test1` .. that is tab delimited values for inserting in tables values.. but that also gives error :(

Comment: If you have your database and tables created, have you tried using the Import wizard in pgAdmin III? (Right click on table -> Import) Aside from that check out the documentation at the link in my answer. But based upon your error, it may be that your datatypes are incorrect in your table vs whats being imported, or vice versa.

Comment: It seams that it is not alowed to use `COPY FROM stdin` with pgAdmin :( thanks, I did checked datatypes as you suggested... thanks for help!